# How to create a custom, reusable dialog box in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm struggling trying to implement a re-usable dialog box in Flex.

All the dialog boxes will be the same size, using an artist drawn image for the background.

There should be a space for a title, and some content.

All dialog boxes will use the same embedded font for the title and a different embedded font for the content.

For some reason I can't get my head around the Flex/MXML/Skins way of doing things.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88tvh.png

A background image, a title in a specific font and position, and a place for content.

**Edit for clarification:**
Sorry my question was not more clear. I do know how to create popups and custom components. What I'm having trouble figure out is how to create different dialogs with different contents, but all sharing the same background, having a place for a title, an area for buttons, etc. I can create dialogs that look the way I want, but then I have to duplicate the code for each dialog and if I want to change something, I have to copy it every other dialog.

Comment: Start by reading this documentation on creating Flex Components: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic, so here is a resumed answer to give you an overall view about what you need to do.
Create one **mxml** component and build the layout using the **Design View** of the Adobe Flash Builder.
Add **[Bindable]** variables for the dynamic values, ie:

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var title:String;

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="titleLbl" text="{title}"/>
```

To show the popup use the AS code below:

```
var popup:YourMXML = YourMXML(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,YourMXML,true));
popup.title = "Your title";
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not more clear. I do know how to create popups and custom components. What I'm having trouble figure out is how to create different dialogs with different contents, but all sharing the same background, having a place for a title, an area for buttons, etc.

Comment: you will have one mxml with the background, title and area for buttons... so when you create the instance of the component to show in the popup, you set the title by the bindable variable, and add the buttons dynamically (http://neerajcse.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/dynamically-creating-and-adding.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for creating Custom Dialog
I made the `text` in both the labels bindable so that I can assign string text to title and message without bothering that the respective component is created or not.

Learn more about [data binding](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html) and [Bindable metadata tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html) to get the insight what is happening actually.

CustomDialog.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300" backgroundImage="@Embed('y3jqqq5x.jpg')" backgroundSize="100%">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]private var _title:String;
        [Bindable]private var _message:String;

        public function set title(value:String):void
        {
            _title = value;

        }

        public function set message(value:String):void
        {
            _message = value;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="lblTitle" horizontalCenter="0" y="10" text="{_title}" fontSize="30"/>
    <mx:Label id="lblMsg" width="250" height="160" horizontalCenter="0" y="100" text="{_message}" fontSize="14"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Use below function to create custom dialog in your AS3 code somewhere like this

```
private function showAlert():void
        {
            var popup:CustomDialog = new CustomDialog();
            popup.title = "Title Goes Here";
            popup.message = "Content goes here."
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, Application.application as DisplayObject, true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
        }
```